# How to get the doc's _version field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use this command to get a document:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/flume-2016-08-19/_search?size=1'
```

But I just get these five fields: "_index", "_type", "_id", "_score", and "_source". How do I also get the "_version" field?

Comment: Hi zmy, and welcome to Stack Overflow. To make your question better, can you describe any attempts you've tried to fix the problem yourself, backed up with links to the official documentation where relevant, and describe why those haven't worked?

Comment: @VinceBowdren,Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add the `version` parameter

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/flume-2016-08-19/_search?size=1&version=true'
                                                                        ^
                                                                        |
                                                                     add this
```